# How to construct a Path "with zero elements"?

Tags: java, file, nio

I'm about to write a test of a custom FileVisitor which requires the filename of a path.

The documentation of [Path's getFileName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName()) reads

> Returns:
>       a path representing the name of the file or directory, or null if this path has zero elements

Apart from using a mock - which I try to avoid - how do I construct a Path with zero elements?

- Paths.get("") - requires a non-null argument, the empty string is one element
- new File("").toPath() - requires also a non-null argument, the empty string is one element, too
- anything like Paths.get(".") or Paths.get("./") also have non-zero elements

For all of these, the filename is never null.

Probably it's a behavior of the WindowsFileSystem implementation in Java.
Does anyone know if other implementation of FileSystem behave differently and it's actually possible, that getFileName() returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(At least on OSX) `java.nio.file.Paths.get('/')` results in such a zero-element `sun.nio.fs.UnixPath`.

Comment: omg - surprise, surprise - it's actually the same on windows, I didn't check for it before because I didn't expect it to behave differently to './' ... that was it, thanks!